# How can I clear the entire screen in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am using the graphical mode (`AL=12h`) and I want to draw some lines and then clean the screen and again draw some lines.

```
mov ah,06
mov al,00
mov bh,07
mov ch,00
mov cl,00
mov dh,24
mov dl,79
int 10h
```

I used the above code but it stopped at `int 10h`.
I want to do something like this:

```
draw_vrt 320,0

draw_hrz 0,240   

mov ah,06
mov al,00
mov bh,07
mov ch,00
mov cl,00
mov dh,24
mov dl,79
int 10h
    
draw_vrt 320,0
            
draw_hrz 0,240
```

Comment: The entire screen can be cleared by setting the videomode. 
[Int 10/AH=06h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0096.htm) scrolls up by AL text lines (30 if AL=0) . I tried it in DosBox and it didn't *stop* unexpectedly. Be more specific.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't go to lines     
 draw_vrt 320,0         
draw_hrz 0,240
that are in end of code, why

Comment: Invokation of `int 10h` seems OK in TurboDebugger. It might be a bug in your emulator. BTW are you aware that the videomode 12h has 30 text lines and not 25?

Comment: Reading the manual we see that *emu8086* only supports video modes **0**, **3**, and **19**. Your mode 12h is not amongst these! Nonethesless I tried it out and yes, it produces some sort of a 80x60 (characters) screen that doesn't function at all. It has been said numerous times already: "**emu8086 is broken software**".

Answer (score 2):

This [set-video-mode (AH=0 / int 10h)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H) BIOS call worked for me, setting video mode = 3

```
;Clear screen
mov ax, 3
int 10h
```